# Why IIS hosted file display different result on localhost and machinname url?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have hosted my asp.net site on my my computer(Windows7)
When i access my hosted site with localhost url i am getting the below given result which is proper

[image]

and when i access my same hosted site with machine name in url i am getting different result (wrong)
[image]

I don't know what the issue with Machinename url and localhost url why the same site giving me different result.

Comment: sorry, but our magic crystal balls are at home, so we can't magically peer into your servers to examine your configuration and code. so... since guessing is the only option left to us, I'm going to blame it on the dog that walked past you last week... one of its hairs landed on you and somehow managed to get sucked into your server, causing the harddrive to get shifted from its normal position by 0.01mm. given how small bits are on drives these days, that translates to around 40 pixels of shift on your average modern LCD.

Comment: For solution please follow this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722921/local-website-renders-differently-using-ip-address-or-machine-name-vs-localhos