# Same HTML CSS Renders different depending on Single Sign On

Tags: html, css

I am using IE11 to access one of our in-house websites. The website employs `single-sign-on`. I am on the same domain as this server.

When I access the website using the server name I am not challenged for a user/pass and the website renders as expected.

When I access the same website using an IP, I am prompted for a user/pass after which, the fonts are rendered slightly heavier, causing table/cell contents to wrap.

The website needs to be run in Compatibility Mode and both the IP and server names are listed. The compatibility is taking effect on both as other incompatibility issues are resolved.

The CSS file is accessible using server name and IP. The IE menu options `View>Text Size`, `View>Encoding` and `View>Style` for both sites are the same. I have also cleared my browsers cache. etc.

When I inspect the element (via F12), both the Style and Calculated Style are the same. Both have "sans-serif 8pt".

When checking the access log on the server, the HTTP responses are the same for when I access via server name or IP.

Unfortunately, due to organizational standards, I have no other browser implementation to `double-check` this.

Any ideas what can cause the font to render differently?

Comment: Check inspect element under tab computed --> font-weight. Maybe something bleeds over from the login prompt and you need to declare the `font-weight: normal` in your css.

Comment: Are you sure you are not zoomed in on one of the sites? Zoom settings are per URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. Zoom is the same for both sites. font-weight is the same when inspected, but yes it appears if via server name font-weight=400 and via IP is it =500 or =600.

Comment: _“Unfortunately, due to organizational standards I have no other browser implementation to double-check this.”_ - can you perhaps at least use the “Save page as …” feature in IE? Then you could do that for both versions, and transport the resulting folders to a different machine, to do more in-depth tests there … (This might not necessarily reproduce the problem, but maybe you get lucky.)

Comment: Nice idea. I saved both to disk, did a file comparison and the files matched. Opening both files from disk in IE gave the same format. Ironically the format on **both** files when read from disk had the unwanted format as the page via IP. Is there maybe something in IE security, which when accessed from a different zone renders the page in a 'kind of' safe mode?

Comment: Does IE display both sites in the same document mode? (Press F12 and see what version number it says by the document mode icon.)

Comment: Duplicate of [Local website renders differently using (IP address or machine name) vs localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722921/local-website-renders-differently-using-ip-address-or-machine-name-vs-localhos)    Adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" ...> resolved this issue.